# Powershell : Convert MariaDB query to String

Tags: mysql, string, powershell, mariadb

Can you help me to convert the below query into string $query ?

```
$arg1 = "--user=root" 
$arg2 = "--password=" + $dbPsw
```

```
$query = @("INSERT INTO `characters` (`account_name`,`obj_id`,`char_name`,`phone`) VALUES  ('John',1000,'John',1234567890);")
```

```
$arg3 = "--execute="+ $query
Start-Process "mysql.exe " -ArgumentList @($arg1,$arg2,$arg3)
```

or into splatting.
Mysql returns only the commands list

Thank so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `Start-Process`. Just run the command. (PowerShell is a shell, after all. One of the jobs of a shell is to run the commands you enter.)

One thing to watch out for is that the backquote (`) character is an escape character in PowerShell, so you will have to double those:

```
mysql "--user=root" "--password=$dbPsw" "--execute=INSERT INTO ``characters`` (``account_name``,``obj_id``,``char_name``,``phone``) VALUES ('John',1000,'John',1234567890);"
```

If the `mysql` command is not in the path, you will need to specify the path to it; e.g.:

```
C:\MYSQL\mysql "--user=root" ...
```

If the `mysql.exe` program is in a path that contains white space, use the invocation (`&`) operator; e.g.:

```
& "C:\Program Files\MYSQL\mysql.exe" "--user=root" ...
```

Comment: Hi Bill ,  I 've got the same problem . see the image pls https://prnt.sc/qliskc The 'a' letter is yellow colored and the output console is like this https://prnt.sc/qlit6t There is no 'a' letter in the output. Mysql returns the Error 1064 (42000)  :|

Comment: Sorry, forgot about backquotes. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Bill for the backquote explanation. Works.